# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS without Redirect 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to have https by default on my site, so I used this .htaccess code to redirect all http traffic to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Everything works great, except that website receives many POST requests coming to old http:// address, and POST data is lost when 301 is used. I can NOT stop POST requests from coming to old http:// address because they come from PHP-based scripts (installed on clients' servers), so my only possible options seem to be 307 or 308 redirects (because they keep POST data).

However, redirect 307 is considered as temporary, while I plan to use https permanently, so it doesn't seem to be the best choice? Of course, I can use 308, but this one seems to be "new" and isn't properly supported by all browsers (according to many comments I found on stackoverflow). Maybe someone knows a better rewrite rule to be used in .htaccess?

P.S. I know the best idea is to use 301 redirect and modify scripts to post data to https by default (and I did so already), but it may take a very long time while all clients will update scripts on their servers, that's why another workaround is needed too.

Comment: Is the data in the POST requests data that you wish to be secured? If not, your easiest option may be to add an exception for that endpoint, and redirect to HTTPS afterwards; if it is, you will need to update the PHP scripts your clients use.

Comment: @AdrianWragg The data sent in those http post requests is _not_ encrypted anyway the moment the requests arrive. Things have already gone wrong at that point in time, the data has already been exposed. Nothing the OP can do against that. So redirecting to insist on an https post request does not make any sense. That is why your suggestion to implement an exception clearly does make sense!

Comment: Adrian, that sounds interesting. These POST requests don't contain any sensitive information, so that may work. In other hand, I would prefer using a single protocol (https) for all requests by default.

Comment: @MindaugasLi You can't use "a single protocol" since you yourself already state that clients send http requests. You cannot somehow magically prevent or change what clients do. All you can do is deal with the requests best you can and then redirect _afterwards_, when sending the reply.

Comment: @arkascha Sorry, I deleted my response (it was a bit of an over-reaction). I wanted to make the point that if the data did need to be encrypted, then redirection is the wrong approach.

Comment: @MindaugasLi If you only want a single protocol, you need to force clients to update. Give them a timescale, then turn off http.

Comment: Got the point. Since I didn't hear any suggestion "use 308 redirect", I guess my thoughts this redirect is not "safe" are correct?

Comment: It does depend upon browser support; however, this is information you do have access to, through analytics and/or the client identifier that the browser sends on its request. That would give you some idea of how your users' browsers are likely to cope.

Comment: All the POST requests are made not from browsers, but from PHP scripts directly using CURL. Tested with redirect 308 on different servers with different PHP versions, seems PHP CURL supports it properly. I'm only concerned what may happen when some visitor visits website's homepage with browser that doesn't support 308.

Comment: How about 308 on the endpoint, 301 on the homepage? However, given that the URL within the PHP script will be hard-coded, what advantage would 308 give anyway over 307 - does PHP curl cache redirections?

Comment: 301 combined with 308 sounds very good. I prefer not to use 307 because of Google and other search engines - I want them to note that transition from http to https was permanent, so my homepage is always indexed as https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the 301, change your conditions to these:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
```

If your clients' legacy scripts use *any* other method, you will have to change the second condition to include it, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(?:POST|PUT)$
```

Normal requests/crawling will always start with `GET` or `HEAD` thus be forced to use https, so subsequent requests will also use it. Make sure all the URLs in your site's content are relative or root-relative.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the best solution for now